# MailChimp subscribe popup not displaying but displaying after admin login

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I am using MailChimp subscribe popup on my Wordpress website. I am getting one issue. I added the below code on my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us5.list-manage.com","uuid":"e47ee5fe210b931aa5a748840","lid":"2b074a0a8b","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
```

I am not getting the popup on my website but if I log in to the WordPress and refresh the page then I am getting the popup.
I checked in the console I am getting the error

> TypeError: window.dojoRequire is not a function

Comment: I suggested moving the second script to a document ready handler but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, Is it working from your side?

Comment: Yes, both of my solutions worked for me. But then your original code did too: I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working from my  side. I just copy and paste it